# How do I convert a file from plain text to a list variable?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python program and it seems that whenever I open it with this line of code active:
`content = open('Word_list.txt').read().splitlines()` it just closes itself (by open I mean double clicking it from file explorer, works fine every other way). I tried with a small list variable and my program works file when it's like that so I need to convert a 4MB file (4,250,000 lines) into a python list variable. Is there any way to do that and will there be any slowdowns because of what i'm doing here?

Oh, and I should mention that I tried other ways of importing the text file (for loops and whatnot) and that seemed to crash instantly too. Thanks!

Comment: If your program crashes, please provide the exact error message and traceback. Also, please provide a minimal, reproducible example. See the [ask] page for details.

Comment: Hi, the program only crashes when I double click on it, not running it from IDLE or command prompt, so I cant find the exact error. Regardless of that, that is not what I asked in the question.

Comment: I'd recommend use an IDE like Pycharm to get started. Atleast you'll be able to debug your code

Comment: What do you mean with "crash"? It just seems like, you double click the file, the program does its job, terminates and then the window closes. Which is completely expected behaviour

Comment: By crash, I mean the program exits without running further code. I can put an input statement before and after that line of code and it'll run perfectly fine when I run it through IDLE or cmd, but when I double click on it through windows file explorer it'll only run the first input, then close itself. Hence, crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use Notepad++ and their macro system to put the required `" ",`'s over all of the words, completing my objecting using another program instead of python.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are running it through Explorer the window is closing before you can see an error message, so add some error handling code:

```py
try:
    content = open('Word_list.txt').read().splitlines()
except Exception as exc:
    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    input()
```

Comment: I tried doing that and apparently it cannot find the word_list.txt file. Strange.

Comment: Try adding `import os` `print(os.getcwd())` into the except block to print out the current working directory.